# Is there any ACK-like mechanism for PostgreSQLs logical decoding/replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Is there a way for a replication client to say whenever they it was able to successfully store the data, or is it that PostgreSQL is streaming pending data to the client and the moment data leave network interface it is considered delivered?

I'd think that client has a chance to say "ACK - I got the data", but I can't seem to find this anywhere... I'm simply wondering what if the client fails to store the data (e.g. due to power failure) - isn't there a way to get it again from Postgres?

General info here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/logicaldecoding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own Q.

After doing much more reading, I can say there is ACK-like mechanism there.

Under some conditions (e.g. on interval) server will ask logical replication consumer to report what was the last piece of data that was persisted (i.e. flushed to disk or similar). Then and only then server will treat data up to that reported point delivered for given replication channel.